# How to pass local variables to ssh scope in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am writing the bash script, which has to perform some of the commands on remote server via ssh. The script has two major parts:

Part 1:
Using local variables $A and $B

Part 2:
Execute commands on remote server as follows:

`ssh -T user@servername  << 'EOF'
...
Using local variables $A and $B
...
EOF`

The problem is that local variables $A and $B are not available within scope of ssh commands on remote server. As far as I understand the variables $A and $B outside and within ssh scope are not the same.

So my question is how to pass local variables from bash script to ssh scope?
One more note, the part 2 is pretty big so I can't use "one liner" after ssh.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce on a FreeBSD box. The output of this simple bash script:

`echo $1
echo $2
ssh -T localhost <<EOF
echo foo
echo $1
echo $2
echo bar
EOF`

when called as ./tst.sh abc def is as expected:

`abc
def
foo
abc
def
bar` (newlines removed by the comment formatting but is definitely not an answer)

Comment: Hard to say why you can't reproduce this problem. I am using Centos OS box. Try to use real remote server, not a localhost.

Comment: What happens if you use my own script with localhost and with your remote server?

Comment: Replace ssh -T localhost <<EOF
with
ssh -T localhost <<'EOF'
and you will reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with ssh but is only related to *here documents* in bash or any other Posix shell.

Man page for bash says in the here document paragraph:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word. **If any characters in word are quoted**, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and **the lines in the here-document are not expanded**. If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. In the latter case, the character sequence `\<newline>` is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and ` .

As you quote `EOF`, you explicitely ask the shell not to replace the `$1` and `$2` variables.

The most robust way is to not quote EOF and consistently quote all others special characters in the here document.

For example, if your *here document* contained something like:

```
ssh -T user@servername << 'EOF'
for f in /var/log/messages*
do echo "Filename: " $f
done
EOF
```

you could rewrite it with no quotes around EOF but with one inside `$`:

```
ssh -T user@servername << EOF
for f in /var/log/messages*
do echo "Filename: " \$f
done
EOF
```

That way all unquoted varibles would be interpolated.

---

Alternatively, if the server allows it, you can try to pass the 2 parameters as environment variables.

Say you want to use the names `PARAM1` and `PARAM2`. The `sshd_config` file on the server should contain the line `AcceptEnv PARAM1 PARAM2` because by default and for security reasons no environment variable is accepted.

You can then use:

```
export PARAM1=$1
export PARAM2=$2
ssh -T -o SendEnv=PARAM1 -o SenEnv=PARAM2 user@servername  << 'EOF'
...
Using variables $PARAM1 and $PARAM2
...
EOF
```

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for explanation. 

The reason I am using quoted EOF is that inside "here document" among other things I have the code:

`
ssh -T user@servername  << 'EOF'

for f in /var/log/messages* ;
do
        echo "Filename: " $f        
done

EOF
`

This code prints empty strings with unquoted EOF and works as expected (prints file names) with quoted EOF

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way to directly tell ssh to use local variables but I'll quickly answer and mention that you could use a script that wraps the ssh with code that inserts the variables remotely where you will have access to them once you get control of the command prompt.